# Selection of Active Cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and  was learning it via doing exercises, one of the first macros was to color a box red If I click on a macro button. I recorded a macro initially to check whats the VBA code it uses to do that

```
Sub MakeMeRed()
'
' MakeMeRed Macro
'
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 192
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

I googled around found that there is another method to select active cell, so I was trying that method to fill the cell.

```
Sub TestMacro()
'
' TestMacro Macro
'
    With ActiveCell
        '.Value = "250"
        .Color = 200
    End With
End Sub
```

But this code does not work, it does not fill the color of selected cell. Can you point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Change `ActiveCell` to `Selection.Interior`

Comment: and change .color to .interior.color.  On a sidenote, it is not wise to use ActiveCell, it is better to reference to cells explicitly. For example A1 becomes Thisworkbook.Thisworksheet.Cells(1,1) (where you can replace thisworkbook and thisworksheet by explicit workbooks or worksheets)

Comment: Hey @Scott, any reason Active Cell doesn't work, because as per my understanding, it also points towards the current cell , can you please let me know the difference and when to use when

Comment: and change `200` to `vbRed` (optionally, just wanted to write it, so they are 3)

Comment: You can use `ActiveCell.Interior`, but if you have selected more than one cell only the active cell will change.  With selection is all the selection.  If you are only chosing one cell then `ActiveCell` = `Selection` but with many it does not.

Comment: @avabhishiek When `Selection` represents a single cell, it is equivalent to `ActiveCell`. However the first code uses `[Selection/ActiveCell].Interior.Color` while the second uses `[Selection/ActiveCell].Color`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are `2` ways to refer to the color, inside the cell.

Using the `ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex` and `ActiveCell.Interior.Color`. `ActiveCell.Interior.Color` can get 4 different values.

```
Sub TestMacro()

    With ActiveCell
        .Value = 1
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        .Offset(1, 1) = 21
        .Offset(1, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        .Offset(1, 2) = 22
        .Offset(1, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed    'vbRed = 255

        .Offset(1, 3) = 23
        .Offset(1, 3).Interior.Color = "&HFF"   'FF = 255; &H is for typeinfo

        .Offset(1, 4) = 24
        .Offset(1, 4).Interior.Color = 255
    End With

End Sub
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To equate the two, ActiveCell in the section is the Selection in the first.  To change the color, you'd need to slide in that Interior portion somewhere.  You can either have `With ActiveCell.Interior` or within the with block `.Interior.Color = 200`.